# CSS hover won't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a 3d box so I need most elements absolutely positioned. Front side is `img`, side is an empty `div` at the moment. Third `div` is a caption div, over the image with opacity of 0. I made simple hover effect to change this opacity to 1, it's working fine in FF, but not in Chrome.

I've seen that there are some bugs when using `hover` on absolute positioned elements in Chrome, but as I've understood, those occur only on elements with `z-index`, maybe I'm mistaken. Anyhow, here's the box code, I could really use some help figuring this one out, as I'm not able to pinpoint the problem Chrome is having.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="img/unyield.jpg" class="image-front">
            <div class="image-caption">
                <span class="caption-content">Unyielding sense</span><br/>
                    <span class="caption-one">cover artwork</span><br/>
                    <span class="read-more">INFO</div>
            <div class="image-side"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS BOX:

```
.image-wrap {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 5%;
margin-top: -225px;
width: 360px;
height: 550px;
perspective: 1000px;
-ms-perspective: 1000px;
-moz-perspective: 1000px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000px;
-o-perspective: 1000px;
}

.image {
position: absolute;
width: 360px;
height: 550px;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform: translateZ(-130px);
-ms-transform: translateZ(-130px);
-moz-transform: translateZ(-130px);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-130px);
-o-transform: translateZ(-130px);
transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
}


.image-front, .image-side {
position: absolute;
width: 360px;
height: 550px;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.image-front {
transform: translateZ(180px);
-ms-transform: translateZ(180px);
-moz-transform: translateZ(180px);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(180px);
-o-transform: translateZ(180px);    
}


.image-side {
transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(180px);
-ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(180px);
-moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(180px);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(180px);
-o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(180px);
border: 1px solid #B8B5B5;
background-color: green;
}
```

And the problematic caption CSS:

```
.image-caption {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
opacity: 0;
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 25px;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.image:hover .image-caption{
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is giving problems `px`  use `deg`

```
.image-front {
transform: translateZ(180px);
-ms-transform: translateZ(180px);
-moz-transform: translateZ(180px);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(180px);
-o-transform: translateZ(180px);    
}
```

see
[stackoverflow.com/questions/hardware-acceleration-in-css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014461/why-does-enabling-hardware-acceleration-in-css3-slow-down-performance/10114994#10114994)
and [css-performance-relative-to-translatez0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814178/css-performance-relative-to-translatez0)

Comment: I don't have problems rotating the box, the trouble is that `caption div` won't change opacity on hover. I posted the whole transform code because the problem might be in html as well as in css, and I just can't see it.

Comment: animations and rotations consume hardware, and to minimize this chrome does not work very well with `px`, use `deg`. try changing the px by deg or not use any values, it is also acceptable

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it now, got it to work, although I'll have to restyle everything. Thanks.